# Python exe - Cx_Freeze - ImportError DLL load failed

Tags: python, dll, environment, cx-freeze, unqlite

In my machine (Windows), I can use my executable of my python program. But if I try on the machine of another person(Windows), it doesn't work.

The executable blocks at the line :
from unqlite import UnQLite

I have fixed his dependency in packages variable:
options={'build_exe':{'include_files':includefiles,'packages': ['Cython'],'includes':['unqlite']}}

And if I look at the folder where it puts the exe, the unqlite.pyd is there...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have finally found the solution.

I took a monitor software to look at the DLL load in my machine.
I filtred all files with my process and the DLL in loaded path.

In one hand, it was **one python DLL** which were missing. On an other hand, Cython expected **one library from microsoft visual C++ runtime environnement**.

*After adding these DLL manually in the program folder and in the setup, my program worked.*